# removing Items from ToopStripMenuItem dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms

How do i dynamically remove a ToolStripMenu Item. I have two events that fire one to add a name and one to remove a name.  Adding names works.  Removing does not.  When i debug my remove i can see that {Poco} in in the DropDownItems.  However when i call remove it does not get removed

```
// Adding items works as expected
ToolStripMenuItem mi = new ToolStripMenuItem("Poco");
mi.CheckOnClick = true;
myToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(mi);
```

i have tried a lot of things.. what i thought would work was this

```
// This does not work .. how do i fix this?
myToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.RemoveByKey("Poco");
```

what is the correct way of removing name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [ToolStripItemCollection.Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25b5ws77(v=VS.90).aspx) property allows you to seek by the item name - as long as it's set for the object itself - so if I assume one cannot add duplicate strings as the menu items, initializing the object with the text to display along with its name should enable you to remove it later:

```
ToolStripMenuItem mi = new ToolStripMenuItem("Poco"){ Name = "Poco" };
```

and then further on your processing remove it with the same code you have (I *assume* it should work):

```
//Should now work based on MS's comment for the Name property:
//The Name property can be used as a key into the ToolStripItemCollection.
myToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.RemoveByKey("Poco");
```

I unfortunately can't test it at the moment, no .NET on this Mac. :-) However, I'm pretty sure you can **Remove()** it by directly referencing the object in the collection:

```
myToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Remove(myToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems["Poco"]);
```

Again, too bad I can't test right away for a definite answer.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. +1